# Finite population correction for Binomial distribution without Normal approximation

Tags: binomial-distribution, hypergeometric-distribution, finite-population

I would like to evaluate the quantile function for a binomially-distributed random variable $X\sim Bin(n,p)$, where $n\ge 1000$. There are a couple of problems:

1. The number of trials $n$ is very close to population size $N$, meaning $n\times p\times (1-p)$ is an underestimate for $Var(X)$.
2. $p$ is very close to 1, meaning that the normal approximation will not work.

I am not sure how to obtain an appropriate distribution function for $X$ in such a scenario. Had $p$ been further away from 1 I would have used the normal approximation with variance corrected for a finite population.

Comment: Unclear what use you will make of the quantile function when you get it. (1) Binomial is exactly the right model if sampling is with replacement. If you're sampling with replacement, then population size $N$ is irrelevant. (2) How close will $p$ be to $1?$ // Why not use the exact binomial quantile function `qbinom` (in R, similar procedures available in many other software programs)?

Comment: A colleague has rightly pointed out to me that the solution is provided by the hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: Approaching the full population is indeed equivalent to a collapse of the notion of sample replacement. Fortunately, the hypergeometric distribution then provides a suitable model.